# Functions like iface.actionSelect().trigger() not working in Plugin?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I want to activate the 'selection Button' in the attribute Toolbar with a click on a button. I always get the error that my class object has no attribute 'iface'.

What am I missing here?

(I am relatively new to building plugins)

I imported everything i need (?):

`from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import uic
from qgis.gui import *
import os
from qgis.core import *
import processing
from qgis.gui import QgisInterface
from qgis.utils import iface`

Code looks like this:

`self.button.clicked.connect(self.actionSelection)`

```
def actionSelection(self):

    lyr.removeSelection()
    self.iface.setActiveLayer(lyr)
    self.iface.actionSelect().trigger()
```

lyr.removeSelection works fine, but the two functions below don't! 
I get: 'class' object has no attribute 'iface'..

My class looks like this:

```
WIDGET, BASE = uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(pluginPath, 'Tool.ui'))
class RandomClass(WIDGET, BASE):
```

I call it like this in my 'main class':

```
    def run(self):

       self.gui = RandomClass(self.iface.mainWindow())
       self.gui.show()
```

Could somebody help me?

Comment: Did you use the **Plugin Builder**? This creates a basic template of a plugin which should have `iface` readily available. Otherwise you would probably need to include `self.iface = iface` in your `def __init__(self, iface)` function.

Comment: No I didn't. Can't use it. When I click on generate it get the following error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/Marco Preuß/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins\\...\\Makefile'

---I did put self.iface = iface in my main class.

---If I add self.iface = iface in my functionality class I get the error: 

'QMainWindow' object has no attribute 'actionSelect'...

Comment: QGIS is sensitive to non-ASCII characters so it may have issue with your username. Try generating it in 'C:/" and if it works, move it to the plugins directory.

Comment: i get the message in red letters: 'Your plugin will overwrite the existing contents!', then i click on generate and it fails.

In every folder location...

Comment: But I have a nice template and all my Plugins work fine with it. But these iface functions just won't work.. it's making me crazy